# Is there reason to avoid slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

Digging into some Java logging stuff, and question about [*slf4j*](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). It seems awfully convenient, always doing the logging same way in .java files, worrying only about logger name, then doing all logging configuration by having right .jar and .properties/.xml files.

What are the reasons to use or not to use *slf4j* by default in any project?

In this particular case, log4j will actually doing the logging (some to file, some to stdout, some to database), and it is a maven project.

I'm hoping for simple "yeah, go for it" or "no, using slf4j is asking for trouble X" from somebody with experience.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691058/best-logging-system and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516932/difference-between-slf4j-and-log4j

Comment: i dont see any reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been logging over the `SLF4J` API for 1.5 years now. Before that we used `log4j` directly. Now we use `jboss.logging`, with a `logback` intermezzo and had to change zero lines in our code for all the framework changing.

So, go for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use slf4j. It's the standard common logging interface of today and it finally does it right regarding the plugging in of actual logging implementations. Logback as the implementation is highly recommended, it is the successor of log4j, done by the same guy who quit log4j to it from the start, but straightening out the issues that couldn't be straightened out in log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually ended up not using slf4j, but instead using log4j directly, because slf4j just kept on using `JDK14LoggerAdapter` instead of `Log4jLoggerAdapter` or LogBack, and I got fed up trying to get it to work by tweaking dependencies...

The project in question is Jenkins plugin built with Maven2, that may have been the reason of complications. It really did not work by "just put these dependencies to .pom".

So, to answer my own question, a reason to not use slf4j is: less moving parts, less dependencies, less manuals and docs to read through, less questions to ask at SO/mailing lists.

Comment: The only way slf4j can use the JDK14LoggerAdapter is because you (or something you use) depend on the sfl4j-jdk14 bridge.  As we have used slf4j for years both with and without Maven it indicates to me that the pain point here is not slf4j but Maven experience.  You may want to see http://slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL for tips on Maven dependencies.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm going for slf4j after all. The "trick" is to not worry about it at development phase, then figure out where to put dynamic logging stuff when deploying. It only gets difficult, when one wants to control logging but can't control deployment.

Comment: I suggest you do as we do.  Make it a two step process.  First step is building the various jar artifacts.  The second step is creating a deployment.  This separation makes many things clearer, and having two steps give  you much more flexibility.